# svnsync: E200014 Base checksum mismatch Error

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

We are using svnsync.exe tool to sync the master database to the mirror. AFter syncing some of the revisions getting the following error ,

```
Transmitting file data .svnsync: E200014: Base checksum mismatch on '/dummy/test.c':

expected:  0da1996b426ea281ac8760a8836b375e
actual:  ff4dd221072b56ee719517e5aa0d756c
```

Note that we have used subversion 1.7.5 binaries.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can anyone help to resolve this error

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one of your repositories has a corrupted revision. You need to restore a backup or manually repair the corruption. Manual repair is a complex operation that may require re-creating the repository and using svnadmin dump and load to replace broken revisions with a placeholder 'padding' revision. Therefore, backup restore is the best recovery option.

You should consider replacing `svnsync`-based replication with [VDFS](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/multisite-replication/), and also [enable scheduled backup](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00106/) and [scheduled repository verification](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00115/).